# Is choice provable if we add parameter free definability to ZF?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

If we add the following $\omega$-inference rule to $\sf ZF$, would that entail the axiom of Choice?

$\textbf{Definability: }$ if $\phi_1,\phi_2, \phi_3,...$ are all formulas in which only symbol "$y$" occurs free, and "$y$" never occur bound, and that doesn't use the symbol "$x$", and $\psi$ is a formula in which only symbol "$x$" occurs free, and "$x$" never occur bound; then:

$\underline {[i=1,2,3,...; \\ \forall x \, (x=\{y \mid \phi_i\} \to \psi)]} \\ \forall x: \psi$

In English: if a parameter free formula holds for all parameter free definable sets, then it holds for all sets.

Comment: Mind explaining the rule in words? I read it as "if $\phi(\{y\mid \psi_i\})$ holds for all $i$ we can conclude $\forall x \phi(x)$", but this is trivially inconsistent

Comment: @ℋolo, why it's inconsistent?

Comment: I misread, I thought that your rule apply to "every collection of formulaes", if $\psi_i$ is an enumeration of all formulaes what-so-ever, then it is consistent (assuming ZFC is consistent) and it satisfy even **global** choice: you can well order the universe by considering formulaes *with* ordinal parameters, this can be translated into stages of von Neumann hierarchy (or any other continuous hierarchy) using reflection, and because the "definability" relation on *sets* is definable you can define a well-ordering on the universe

Comment: @ℋolo, parameter free definability on sets is NOT definable!

Comment: If $X$ is a set, the relation "$X \models a\text{ is definable with ordinal parameters}$" is definable, and I only used that (and you can replace "ordinal parameters" with pretty much anything that makes sense in $X$)

Comment: My argument is basically the same argument as "$HOD$ satisfy (definable) global choice"

Comment: @ℋolo, "definable with ordinal parameters" is indeed definable but "is parameter free definable" is not definable.

Comment: But your Definability rule implies "every set is ordinal-definable", as "x is ordinal definable" is a parameter-free statement that holds for all sets that are definable without parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that "$x$ is *ordinal* definable" is definable without parameters by the formula "there exists $\alpha$ s.t. $\alpha$ is ordinal and there exists a finite sequence $\overline \beta$ of ordinals and a Godel number $n$ such that $V_\alpha\models'\text{The formula that n represent defines $x$}'$"

From the reflection theorem we know that "$\phi_k$ defines a set $A$" implies that there exists some ordinal $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models '\phi_k\text{ defines $A$}'$, so we can conclude that $$[i=1,2,3,...; \\ \forall x \, (x=\{y \mid \phi_i\} \to \text{$x$ is ordinal definable})]$$

From the $\omega$-rule "Definability" we get $\forall x(\text{$x$ is ordinal definable})$, in other words we have that $V=HOD$.

And $V=HOD$ is in equivalent to "$V$ admits a (definable) global well ordering".

Comment: Conversely, $V = HOD$ gives us OP's rule. For suppose there is some $x$ such that $\neg \psi(x)$. Then take $i$ such that $\phi_i(y)$ is the statement "$y$ is an element of the least $x$ such that $\neg \psi(x)$" (where "least" is under the canonical well-ordering of $HOD$). Then take the least $x$ such that $\neg \psi(x)$; then we have $x = \{y \mid \phi_i(y)\}$, and thus $\psi(x)$; contradiction.